# Recursively delete hidden directory & its files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, shell-script

I want to delete all hidden directoris from  a directory and its sub-directory.
 I also use `rm -rf .directory_name` this command is iterative command I want to a recursive command. 
Please anybody help me??

Comment: Why do you call `rm -rf` iterative?  The `-r` stands for recursive. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this (although it's not clear what you mean when distinguishing "iterative command" from "recursive command", since `rm -rf` is both recursive *and* iterative):

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -type d -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```

Once you're happy, remove `echo` from the option arguments to `-exec` to remove the listed directories.

Comment: I'd upvote that again if I could. Great answer!